# habilitar rewrite no Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache

Galera estou tentando habilitar o rewrite no linux ubunto e não estou conseguindo, é diferente do WAMP do windows, alguém me da um caminho?
Fiz este código mas não funciona!

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

para tal, você deve abrir o terminal do ubuntu, e digitar os seguintes comandos, da mesma maneira que esta neste [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache) do Ask Ubuntu.

execute no terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

depois reinicie o webserver apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```